# How can I make the table borders of an html field (edited with CKeditor) visible?

Tags: html, ckeditor, report, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to print a content of a html field formated with CKeditor. To do so I changed the field `note` to an html field like this:

```
from openerp import models, fields


class CustomSaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    note = fields.Html(
        string='Terms and conditions',
    )
```

And I changed the report as well to print the html code:

```
<template id="custom_sale_order" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//p[@t-field='o.note']" position="replace">
        <p t-raw="o.note" />
    </xpath>
</template>
```

I want to create tables inside the CKeditor and make them visibles in the report (with their borders). It seems there is a [plugin of CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/showborders) that make this, but I don't know if that's going to work well or if its installation is possible.

I also checked how is saved the html field in the database and the tables are saved with the attribute `border="1"`:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
[...]
```

If I print the report as html report the tables are visible, but if I print the report as pdf the borders are invisible.

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem:

First I added a class to the report and a custom style:

```
<template id="custom_sale_order" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//p[@t-field='o.note']" position="replace">
        <div class="ckeditor_field">
            <p t-raw="o.note"  />
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>

<template id="custom_sale_order_style" inherit_id="report.layout">
    <xpath expr="//style" position="after">
        <style type="text/css">
            .ckeditor_field table {
                margin: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
            }

            .ckeditor_field table td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                vertical-align: middle;
                padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
            }

            .ckeditor_field p {
                line-height: 1;
            }

        </style>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

And I also added added another class to the view with the same or similar CSS. I made this to see the tables when I save the field:

```
<record id="view_order_form_wtd" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form.wtd</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">   
        <field name="note" position="replace">
            <field name="note" class="note_wtd" widget="html" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```